# How to import 'negative_cvar' from PyPortfolioOpt?

Tags: python, function

I need to use CVaR from [PyPortfolioOpt](https://pyportfolioopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but I encountered an error.

When I use this code :

```
from pypfopt.objective_functions import negative_cvar
```

I received the error:

```
Import Error:
cannot import name 'negative_cvar' from 'pypfopt.objective_functions' (C:\Users\Saad\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pypfopt\objective_functions.py)
```

Answer (score 1):

`CVaR` was available in PyPortfolioOpt until version 0.5.3, but has since been removed. The project maintainer wrote on GitHub on July 21, 2020:

> Hi guys, thanks for the feedback. CVaR is something I want to add, but it's actually quite hard to do it properly.

See GitHub issue [Plz add your CVaR feature back in #155](https://github.com/robertmartin8/PyPortfolioOpt/issues/155).